# Best way to do this? Add tags as images on product pages

Tags: woocommerce

I am trying to be clever, but this is a bit beyond my abilities.

I have products with tags, these tags denote if something is environmentally friendly or not. Some of these tags are "biodegradable", compostable" and "recycled" for example.

If a product has these tags, I want to echo it on the front end.

I have the code to do this, and it is working as expected:

```
$current_tags = get_the_terms( get_the_ID(), 'product_tag' );

//only start if we have some tags
if ( $current_tags && ! is_wp_error( $current_tags ) ) { 

    //create a list to hold our tags
    echo '<ul class="product_tags">';

    //for each tag we create a list item
    foreach ($current_tags as $tag) {

        $tag_title = $tag->name; // tag name

        echo '<li><img src="/img/tags/'.$tag_title.'.png"></li>';
    }

    echo '</ul>';
}
```

However, the only way to get this working is for me to edit content-single-product.php or single-product.php and place it in my theme in the woocommerce folder.

Is there a better way?

I'd like to control exactly where in the source order of that page it is displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. In functions.php:

```
/**
 * Add test
 */
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product_summary', 'tjobbetest', 5 );

function tjobbetest() {
    $current_tags = get_the_terms( get_the_ID(), 'product_tag' );

    //only start if we have some tags
    if ( $current_tags && ! is_wp_error( $current_tags ) ) { 

        //create a list to hold our tags
        echo '<ul class="product_tags">';

        //for each tag we create a list item
        foreach ($current_tags as $tag) {

            $tag_title = $tag->name; // tag name

            echo '<li><img src="/img/tags/'.$tag_title.'.png"></li>';
        }

        echo '</ul>';
    }
}
```